# If I buy a new disc for a game I already own, does it keep the savefile?

Tags: ps3, physical-media

I have a disc copy of Transformers Fall of Cybertron and it's getting old and I needed replaced with a newer disc. If I insert the new disc into my PS3 will my old save be there? Or will it replace it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there will be, and this applies to every game in general (regardless of Disk version and Download version). It's not like the game is saving data to your disk, it's saving data to the PS3 itself. So, if you change the PS3, you will need to transfer your data to new PS3, but if only just changing disc, you don't need to do anything.